# Silverlight application won't load

Tags: silverlight

i'm trying to get started with silverlight 2.
i have a weird bug. every app i build in vs 2008, when i run it the browser prompts me to install silverlight 2 although it's already installed and i have no problem running other silverlight websites.
i'm trying to build a simple "hello world" application.
i've tried uninstalling and reinstalling.
nothing works, it's very frustrating.
please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this before when the plugin I was running didn't match the SL framework version the app was built against.  Is there any chance you've installed SL 3 but then installed the SL 2 plugin?  Can you post the  tag in your .aspx page that hosts the control?

Comment: <asp:Silverlight ID="Xaml1" runat="server" Source="~/ClientBin/SilverlightApplication2.xap" MinimumVersion="2.0.30523" Width="100%" Height="100%" />

i'm installing the latest version of the plugin, the one i prompts me to install...

and yes i'm sure it's silverlight 2

Comment: Thanks for posting - Just a word about stack overflow, wait to hit the green check mark until your problem is fixed.  Is this running in IIS or Cassini?  If IIS can you post the mime type for .xap?

Comment: Try removing the MinimumVersion="2.0.30523" attribute.